# FLUTTER NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'debugDidSendFirstFrameEvent' was called on null

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

I hope your all staying safe! I have been working through the [NetNinja's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c063ddhWafo&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&index=16&t=0s) tutorial on [Flutter](https://flutter.dev), Google's open source, cross-platform app framework powered by [Dart](https://dart.dev). I have been following along with the tutorials, and have had no problem. However, when I started a new Flutter Project, it's not working. I ran this simple code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => MaterialApp(
  home: IdCard(),
);

class IdCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Id Card"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
      ),   
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I open the app in iOS simulator, I get a blank screen. When I ran on debug mode, I got an error on line 53 of object_patch.dart, which is part of the Dart SDK. The error said `NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'debugDidSendFirstFrameEvent' was called on null`. It was on this line:

```dart
throw new NoSuchMethodError.withInvocation(this, invocation);
```

I am not getting any other errors in the console In VSCode, I ran Debug my code + packages + SDKs, which didn't return errors. `flutter doctor` didn't return iOS or Dart related errors (it complains about android studio). I ran flutter run -v, which returned no errors. The last 1000 lines of it's output are available [here](https://ghostbin.co/paste/u7kzm) (iTerm limits scrollback to 1000 lines.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: ```debugDidSendFirstFrameEvent``` This method is created by you?

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata no this method is part of the Dart SDK.

Comment: I also added an [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/943) on the dart github repo.

Comment: try ```Flutter clean```

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata trying that now. That might clean out some of the SDK files causing problems. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata Now I get a new error. Pasted it [here](https://ghostbin.co/paste/jazgc). Maybe network related? The error message starts on line 907.

Comment: you forgot to invoke it via runApp. it should be:  void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(....))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to runApp.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: IdCard(),
    ));
```

Comment: That works. Thanks to everyone who helped. I am still curious about the other two errors though. It seems the first one is quite common, even when `runApp` is invoked. If anyone has a solution, let me know! Thanks again!

Comment: Accept my answer if it is useful. @PotatoHeadz35